# mysql completely locks up on one simple query

Tags: mysql

i have this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.artist_id AS artist_id,
    t2.name AS track_name
FROM
    media.recording t1,
    media.track_name t2
WHERE
    t1.name = t2.id
GROUP BY
    t1.artist_id,
    t2.name COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

All string fields are utf8_bin, but i need case insensitive distinct artist IDs and their track names because there are many many duplicates like:
Metallica - Sad But True,
Metallica - Sad but true,
Metallica - Sad but True
And i need only one version.

Table "recording" has 11 million rows and "track_name" has 5.5 million rows. Database is Mysql, tables are MyISAM.

Problem is that when i run this query whole mysql locks up. It locks all tables in all databases on this server for around 15 minutes. All queries wait for table lock on all tables in all databases. Shouldn't myisam only lock the tables the query is using (in my case recording and track_name)?

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED** shows:

```
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref           | rows     | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL    | recording_idx_name | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 10805478 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | media.t1.name |        1 |   100.00 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+---------------+----------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

I think hardware is not the issue. Server has **4 CPUs** with **8 cores** (32 cores, 64 threads) and **64GB RAM**. It has **6x SSD** disks in RAID 10.

**my.cnf**

```
max_connections          = 768
key_buffer               = 6G
table_cache              = 15360
read_buffer_size         = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size     = 2M
sort_buffer_size         = 1M
tmp_table_size           = 128M
max_heap_table_size      = 128M
max_allowed_packet       = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size  = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size  = 128M
thread_cache_size        = 64
join_buffer_size         = 1M
```

Please help :)
Thanks!

-Paxxil

Comment: do an upper on the field and the condition and you don't need to worry about case then.  i.e. where upper(t1.column) = upper(t2.column)

that way "Sad But True", "Sad but true" and "Sad but True" are all equal as far as the query is concerned.

Comment: Have you tried using an inner join, instead of querying from two tables? And from the explain you provided, I do believe it's scanning 10,805,478 rows for each row in t2. Using some form of join might make it faster anyway, and solve the locking problem.

Comment: @Brian that is true, but i need array of all artists and their unique songs in one query.

Comment: @letuboy can you provide any example?

Answer (score 0):

Try `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.artist_id AS artist_id,
    t2.name COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS track_name
FROM
    media.recording t1,
    media.track_name t2
WHERE
    t1.name = t2.id
```

MySQL's weakness is `group by`...

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it still locks whole mysql - all databases and all tables. Query execution time is similar to GROUP BY version. Thanks.